Reading Spatial Data with Command Interceptors
In our system we are in the process of implementing a system wide timezone selection in which all dates and times will be viewed as, regardless of where the user is viewing the site from.
The database will store the utc times. What I am attempting to do is use a DbCommandInterceptor to catch all the datetime properties and do the timezone conversion as part of the read from the database through Entity Framework. However, I am running into an exception that is occurring on tables in which we have spatial fields of the type Geometry.

System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException: 'Spatial
readers can only be produced from readers of type SqlDataReader. A
reader of type HomesteadRepository.DataInterception.EFDataReader was
provided.'

The EFDataReader data reader class inherits from DbDataReader, taking the original data reader in through the constructor. 99% of the internal functions use the original data reader to return it's functions, with the only change being the GetDateTime function that performs that date and time adjustements.
public class EFDataReader : DbDataReader
{
    private readonly DbDataReader originalReader;
    public override bool HasRows => originalReader.HasRows;
    public override bool IsClosed => originalReader.IsClosed;
    public override int FieldCount => originalReader.FieldCount;
    public override int RecordsAffected => originalReader.RecordsAffected;
    public override Int32 Depth => originalReader.Depth;
    public override Object this[Int32 ordinal] => originalReader[ordinal];
    public override Object this[String name] => originalReader[name];

    public EFDataReader(DbDataReader originalReader)
    {
        this.originalReader = originalReader;
    }

    public override bool GetBoolean(int ordinal)
    {
        return originalReader.GetBoolean(ordinal);
    }

    public override byte GetByte(int ordinal)
    {
        return originalReader.GetByte(ordinal);
    }

    public override long GetBytes(int ordinal, long dataOffset, byte[] buffer, int bufferOffset, int length)
    {
        return originalReader.GetBytes(ordinal, dataOffset, buffer, bufferOffset, length);
    }

    public override char GetChar(int ordinal)
    {
        return originalReader.GetChar(ordinal);
    }

    public override long GetChars(int ordinal, long dataOffset, char[] buffer, int bufferOffset, int length)
    {
        return originalReader.GetChars(ordinal, dataOffset, buffer, bufferOffset, length);
    }

    public override string GetDataTypeName(int ordinal)
    {
        return originalReader.GetDataTypeName(ordinal);
    }

    public override DateTime GetDateTime(int ordinal)
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime datetime = originalReader.GetDateTime(ordinal);
            datetime = DL.AdjustDateTime(datetime).Value;

            return datetime;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }

    public override decimal GetDecimal(int ordinal)
    {
        return originalReader.GetDecimal(ordinal);
    }

    public override double GetDouble(int ordinal)
    {
        return originalReader.GetDouble(ordinal);
    }

    public override IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return originalReader.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public override Type GetFieldType(int ordinal)
    {
        return originalReader.GetFieldType(ordinal);
    }

    public override float GetFloat(int ordinal)
    {
        return originalReader.GetFloat(ordinal);
    }

    public override Guid GetGuid(int ordinal)
    {
        return originalReader.GetGuid(ordinal);
    }

    public override short GetInt16(int ordinal)
    {
        return originalReader.GetInt16(ordinal);
    }

    public override int GetInt32(int ordinal)
    {
        return originalReader.GetInt32(ordinal);
    }

    public override long GetInt64(int ordinal)
    {
        return originalReader.GetInt64(ordinal);
    }

    public override string GetName(int ordinal)
    {
        return originalReader.GetName(ordinal);
    }

    public override int GetOrdinal(string name)
    {
        return originalReader.GetOrdinal(name);
    }

    public override string GetString(int ordinal)
    {
        return originalReader.GetString(ordinal);
    }

    public override object GetValue(int ordinal)
    {
        return originalReader.GetValue(ordinal);
    }

    public override int GetValues(object[] values)
    {
        return originalReader.GetValues(values);
    }

    public override bool IsDBNull(int ordinal)
    {
        return originalReader.IsDBNull(ordinal);
    }

    public override bool NextResult()
    {
        return originalReader.NextResult();
    }

    public override bool Read()
    {
        if (originalReader != null)
        {
            return originalReader.Read();
        }

        return false;
    }
}

The EFInterceptor command interceptor class inherits from DbCommandInterceptor. The only function overridden is the ReaderExecuted function.
public class EFInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
{
    public EFInterceptor()
    {
    }

    public override void ReaderExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        interceptionContext.Result = new EFDataReader(interceptionContext.Result);
        base.ReaderExecuted(command, interceptionContext);
    }
}

The Entity Framework database context adds the interceptor in it's constructor.
DbInterception.Add(new EFInterceptor());

Is there a way to create and use an interceptor that uses an SqlDataReader or any way in which one could do this conversion as soon as Entity Framework reads from the database without manually having to go to each field and perform the adjustment?
Edits: Changed parameter for GetValue from i to ordinal.
